# How to divide each columns by last row

Tags: r, data.table

```
dx <- data.table(A = rep(1:3, each = 5), B = rep(1:5, 3),
                 C = sample(15), D = sample(15))
```

I want to divide each columns by last row by group A. 
my code is:

```
dx[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x/.N), by=A]
```

but it divides all columns by last row in column one only.

thx advance

Comment: `dx[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[-.N]/x[.N]), by = A]`?

Comment: thx Sotos,it works